# What is the proper way of fetching or using the provided API in Node js,express and integrating in ejs ? Scenerio: login and register post

Tags: node.js, api, express, postman, ejs

Below is the provided API by the client company,well tested in postman. Front-end team has provided ejs template. Now, what is the process of 'fetching that provided API in login and register post section' along with how to integrate in ejs template of login.ejs and register.ejs?
Write your demo code seeing the below postman image.

API:[www.example.com/api/business/v1/attendees/login/event_id](http://www.example.com/api/business/v1/attendees/login/event_id)
[image]

Comment: This is not the place to write the whole code for you. If you are facing an issue at some point then we can help you.

Comment: I mean, what would be the login.js logic for such provided api?

Comment: if you have a `login` and `register` page then now you need to create all the required back-end logic please go through this code once https://github.com/kedarSedai/Login-Register. If you have any confusion then do let me knowow

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question, i know how to create login by creating own api.but the question is api is already provided for me, now what is the logic to call such api in login.js file and render in ejs template

Comment: Give me some time I will write the code for calling an `API` and showing in the `ejs` page.

Comment: Sure.i am searching for post request for login and register.If i get login logic, register will be easy.For api, you can refer the above postman screenshot.

Comment: Any update bro?@kedar

Comment: Here is the answer of this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60340027/calling-external-api-endpoints-when-working-with-node-and-ejs-and-geting-the-det/65812825#65812825